# Why I have this issue when I try to set an height and a vertical scroll on the tbody of an html table?

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am finding some difficulties to add an height with scroll to the **tbody** of this inner table:

[image]

As you can see in my page I have a Jquery accordion menu (I think that this is not a problem) that contains an inner table (highlighted in the red square).

This is the code of my table:

```
<div>
    <table border="1" class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 70%; float: right;">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="14.2%">Codice RM</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Autore Firma</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Data Firma</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Acq Riserva</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Consegna Finale</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Descrizione RM</th>
                <th width="14.2%">Imponibile</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
             <%
                 int count = 0;
                 for (RM currentRM : salDettaglio.getRM()) {
                     String test = currentRM.getAcqRiserva();
                     String evenOrOdd;
                     if((count & 1) == 0) {
                         evenOrOdd = "even";
                     }
                     else {
                         evenOrOdd = "odd";
                     }
                     count++;
                  %>

                  <tr id="rmRow" class=<%=evenOrOdd %> >
                      <td><%=currentRM.getCodiceRm()%></td>
                      <td><%=currentRM.getAutoreFirma()%></td>
                      <td><%=currentRM.getDataFirma()%></td>
                      <td><%=currentRM.getAcqRiserva()%></td>
                      <td><%=currentRM.getConsegnaFinale()%></td>
                      <td><%=currentRM.getDescrizioneRM()%></td>
                      <td><%=currentRM.getImponibile().toString()%></td>
                  </tr>

               <%}%>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

And this the CSS related to this table:

```
table.standard-table-cls {
    border: 1px solid #76818a;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #76818a;
    font: 11px Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 !important;
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table.standard-table-cls th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #76818a;
    border-left: 1px solid #76818a;
    color: #76818a;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 14px 2px 4px !important;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table.standard-table-cls tr.even {
    background-color: #fffece;
}

table.standard-table-cls tr.odd {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Ok, now the problem is that I want to add an **height** to the **tbody** and a scroll to it (if the content overflow the height.

So I add the following CSS (I set the **tbody** as a **block** so I can fix an height to it and I set the overflow to scroll for y):

```
.standard-table-cls > tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And I obtain this tragic result:

[image]

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a max-height and a min-width?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is quite simple (if I do not misunderstand you).

Just add to your code a width, so that the block element get its dimensions:

```
.standard-table-cls > tbody {
display: block;
height: 45px;
width: 70%; <!-- or 400px or something -->
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If I got something wrong please let me know.

**UPDATE**

Although, as suggested by marinersfanfromny, you can make it more dynamic by setting your height as `max-height` and `min-width`, so as soon as the table is higher then 45px it will be scrollable, and it should have at least the width of 70%.

```
.standard-table-cls > tbody {
display: block;
max-height: 45px;
min-width: 70%; <!-- or 400px or something -->
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Adjust the width/height parameters as you wish them to be and you are good to go! To fix the floating, because you want the table to appear on the right side on your screenshot, add another `float: right;` to the code above.

Best regards,
Marian.